# MAMP MySQL databases gone after upgrading MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I used a guide to upgrade MySQL for use with Magento2 and now the databases are gone.

Going to `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql` shows all of the databases but they are not showing up for mysql. I have looked and I can't find the guide to show what it did.

Is there a way to show all the information for MAMP's mysql info? I've looked at PHPINFO but it's not in there.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded from MAMP 3 to MAMP 4.  Prior to upgrading I copied my db folder within my MAMP directory along with my htdocs folder.  After the upgrade I started everything up and my application could not find its DB. I couldn't search and find any of the database files on my drive.

After searching..... I found out the new MAMP upgraded the data folder to mysql56 from mysql. On my system it is found in Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56.  If you just rename the old folder from mysql to mysql56 then all is well.

Comment: remember to restart MAMP after making the changed to DB mysql56 folder.